# Why does my new water heater pilot go out every so often?

Tags: water-heater, pilot-light

My water heater pilot light will go out at most inconvenient times  ever since I installed it. I can light it then days or weeks later it will go out again.

Why?

Comment: Model # of water heater? Are there any sudden drafts in the room - e.g., a door to the outside?

Comment: no inside  its a rheem  not sure on model #

Comment: the heater is inside, it's a rheem  about 2 years old can't find model #

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an air leak in the form of a small crack somewhere?

Comment: Mine goes out every now and then, too. Not on a days or weeks frequency, but it seems that a couple of times a year, I've got to go relight it. Just part of life?

Comment: @FreeMan Once in a while isn't a big deal. But still shouldn't happen. It has been many **years** since I had to light the water heater - exception when new one was installed, but the plumbers did it so I didn't have to (though I do know how to do so).